# hibernate spring execution order stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-stored-procedures

I am using hibernate with spring (for the transaction management) and have a DAO like that

```
@Transactional
class Dao{

public save(Entity e){
//stored an entity
Entity saved = entityManager.merge(e);

//flush the dataset to the db
entityManager.flush();

//updates the saved entity with a stored procedure
entityManger.createNameQuery(STORED_PROCEDURE).setParameter(0, saved.getId()).executeUpdate();
}
}
```

That will be executed in the following environments with different results:

- JUnit: everything works fine here. The entity is stored and the stored procedure updates the saved dataset.
- EJB on a Glassfish: the stored procedure is executed first and then the save operation will be executed (i log the sql commands from hibernate). It seems that the flush is not executed.

As a result the stored entity doesnt include the updates of the stored procedure. I have no idea why the operations are executed in different order on the Glassfish environment and everything works fine at the Junit testcase.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the entity manager created in that two cases? Could it be that in one case you have a persistance unit with some settings, and in the other cases different settings

Comment: The entity manager will be configured via spring. Both environments have different setting:
JUnit: the resource is defined as RESOURCE_LOCAL and a JpaTransactionManager is used
Glassfish: the resource is defined as JTA and a JtaTransactionManager is used

Comment: You got the reason. Your platform transaction manager is probably different.